# Android:Use Of SharedPreference Causes Memory leak

Tags: android, sql, memory-leaks, sharedpreferences

Our Application is using SharedPreference to save data. The application is receiving around 1.5Mb data from server.

After parsing the data I am storing it in SharedPreference. But the save operation is causing around 2mb of Hashmaps on heap (I checked with a memory analyzer tool). So does sharedPrefs use a Heap (I dont think so) or internally while storing, is Editor not clearing the Map Object data Strings? (On Memory Analyzer, data is Shown as HashMap with GC root to SharedPrefs and android.app.ContextImpl (Internal or inner class in android))

Also, which is the better way, using sqlite or SharedPref? Because with sharedPref, the app is working fast and fine. My only problem is this memory leak.

Comment: Most probably for that big amount of data using sql database will give faster results and will eat less memory especially if data change often.

Comment: sharedPreferences are to be used as small storage places across multiple restarts. it does not respond well to huge amount of data being stored... the speed also reduces... best to use a Database or a File storage in SD CARD.

Comment: thanks i have changed my code with sql db

Comment: this answer can help on how-to implement -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/6364642/492918

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could store it into a private file and use a delimiter or something else if there are more then one entry.

However if you have many entries the best way would be to use a database I guess.

This code below would save a string into a file:

```
    public static void WriteSettings(Context context, String data,String filename) {
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    try {
        fOut = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            osw.close();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```